# how i can convert from int[] to List<Integer> in java

Tags: java

I have an array as the integer I want to convert her to List without the use of loops

```
int[] arrya={1,2,3,4,5};
//List<Integer> myList=Arrays.asList(arrya);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of streams

```
int[] arrya={1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arrya).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```